# Rails heroku logs not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

When I run heroku logs nothing happens. The command line get just rendered. No log is given.

My git console:

```
Iceberg@ICEBERG-PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
$ heroku logs

Iceberg@ICEBERG-PC /c/rails/konkurranceportalen (master)
$
```

Comment: I am also having the same issue for couple of hours. May be something wrong with their loggig feature

Comment: Same for me, the feature went down

Comment: Now logs is an addon. Have you activated this?

Comment: Is that just happen yesterday?

Comment: @taro shouldn't be the problem. Even with logging:basic the problem seems to persist.

Comment: It works for one of my apps but not the other. I've sent in a support request to heroku and will respond if I hear anything back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku had an issue with logging that unfortunately went undetected for a while. It should be back to normal now.

Please file a support ticket if you're still seeing issues.

http://status.heroku.com/incident/162
https://support.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

What does `heroku addons` show you? A while back, heroku introduced new logging feature.

```
$heroku addons
logging:expanded
```

if you didn't add the addon, logging:basic or logging:standard, that might be the reason. Works for me.